# How to conditionally allow Back event

Tags: backbone.js

Developing a BackboneJS app with pushState

When user clicks the mouse's back button or clicks the browser's back button, how can I capture the event and do something like:

```
backAction: function(e){
  if (someConditionIsTrue) { preventBackAndDoSomeStuff(); }
  else { doNormalBackEvent() }
}
```

Comment: Nice name :). For your question, you CAN'T there is a indirect way. On clicking back the url may be matches a route. There is a callback defined at the root, apply your logic there.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a listener to [`window.onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate) to get notice when the user hits the back button.